# Select all columns of first table of a form

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to select all columns of the first table in a form.

```
.myform table:first td { color: red }
```

Code Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/fqsLaxzL/1/

Comment: There is a typo when you define the class for your myform. remove the dot from `class=".myform"`. Anyway, see the answer

Answer (score 1):

I edited your fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fqsLaxzL/2/

```
table {
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.myform table:FIRST-CHILD td { color: red }

<form class="myform">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>this</td>
      <td>this</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
          <td>this one too</td>
          <td>this one too</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Please see the actual scenario here -> http://s24.postimg.org/s2obrr7o5/css_selector.jpg
Technically it should apply to all td's under green box. But it is still applying to second table as well. `.search_results_section table:FIRST-CHILD td { display: none; }`